# Is there correct way to set Ngrok file to skip browser warning page

Tags: file, configuration, yaml, ngrok

Here is sample of Ngrok file which I'm using within tunnel:

```
authtoken: somevalue 
version: "2"
tunnels:
  sometunellName 
    proto: http
    addr: 5555
    schemes: 
             - http
             - https
    host_header: rewrite
    request_header:
                  add:
                   - "ngrok-skip-browser-warning:true" 
log_level: debug 
log_format: json 
log: ngrok.log
```

Several common headers didn't give any new result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ngrok-skip-browser-warning:true" header has to be added in the browser as the ngrok cloud side of things has to see it to skip the browser warning. With your config, you've added it in the ngrok cloud so only your app is seeing it.

~ an ngrok employee